# cascading drop down list does not select exact value on fetch operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to get selected name of state in my `drop down list` on fetch operation. It is able to populate  names of state and as well as names of city on the selection of country/state.

Problem: At the data entry time when we select the 2/3 index value of list. then on the fetch operation it won't show as the selected.
To populate the list code is as follows.

```
private DataSet StateNames(string country)
    {
        prop.DS = objBL.PopStates(country);
        if (prop.DS.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ddlStates.DataSource = prop.DS;
            ddlStates.DataTextField = "ColName";
            ddlStates.DataValueField = "Col_ID";
            ddlStates.DataBind();
            ddlStates.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" Select", "-1"));
        }
        else { }

        return prop.DS;
    }
```

To show the already selected & saved value I have wrote the following code:

```
    ds2 = StateNames(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["country"].ToString());
            if (ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string state_name_value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BirthLocCol"].ToString();
                ddlSates.SelectedValue =  Convert.ToString(ddlStates.Items.FindByValue(state_name_value));     
            }
---
```

this code gives the following error:

```
ddlState has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it doesn't exist in the list of items.
```

Please guide me, where I am doing wrong to show the selected value in the `dropdownlist`.

Thank you!

Comment: it's look like when you try to set the selected value at that time your Dataset has been changed that's y it's give you error like that or the value which you are trying to set is not exists in your dataset

Comment: @DhavalPatel thank you for quick response. would you please suggest me the right way to do this..

Comment: you have to first check the value of state_name_value is contains in your dataset if it's exists then you have to set selected item other wise don't set it

Comment: `ds` one is the main data set containing all the records and showing that value perfectly but to load state list I have brought that data using the `state_name_value` in `ds2` ... guide me please  how can i show selected value in state `dropdownlist` control

Comment: did you get the value in state_name_value and it's exists in your state dropdown ?

Comment: Yes boss! it is able to bind the state list and if it is the first value then it will it as `selected value` otherwise it will show the first value only as `selected value` ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70543/discussion-between-dhaval-patel-and-nikhil-g).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use below mentioned code for it, You are trying to convert object to string rather value of it.

```
ddlSates.SelectedValue =  Convert.ToString(ddlStates.Items.FindByValue(state_name_value).Value);
```